# How to click ok on a dialog box using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I got a weird dialog box in web application testing and I am just stuck. Dialog box is a conditional. It displays based on some data we enter. I just need to be able to click OK or press enter if it displays.

[image]

I clicked OK while recording. UFT does not add any code and nothing was added to OR. When I spy, it is not recognizing the ok and does not recognize the dialog box. 
Manually I simply click OK or press enter to handle. Then I wrote the shell way to press enter. It does not do anything.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

How can I handle this dialog box using UFT?

Comment: What happens if there are matches found? If that condition is not satisfied, you can safely assume that your window will be displayed. You can use `WScript` for this but keep following in mind: firstly you have to set focus to your application (which automatically sets the focus to your window) before you run `WScript` command. Second, you cannot step through when testing `WScript.Sendkeys` commands

Comment: I could not follow your answer. How do I focus to window? Can you please share complete code?

Comment: I can't provide code for an application that I have never seen. What happens when a match is found? You can set focus to a window by either using `SetFocus` or simply just clicking on the window

Comment: When I click the dialog box while normal recording, it does nothing. When I spy the dialog box and object on the dialog box, sometimes spy freezes(no respond) and sometimess I see just page title(instead I was looking for dialog box to be recognized). it does not recognize the dialog box. I used insight object, it worked. Others will be running the script in their machines. Not sure yet if it will work on others machine.

Answer (score 2):

you can you insight object to identify the "Ok" button. in case you are not able to spy it.

Comment: Bare in mind that `Insight objects` are volatile. i.e. if your screen resolution changes (or if someone other than you tried to execute the script on their machine with different resolution), `Insight object` might not be recognised even if it's there

Answer (score 0):

If this is the browser's regular dialog (javascript's `alert`) UFT supports dismissing it using [`Browser(...).HandleDialog`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~Browser.html#HandleDialog).

If this works then it should also have recorded the `HandleDialog` step, if it doesn't it may be a defect in UFT, I suggest contacting MicroFocus's support.